# How to dispatchEvent key up in a for loop and waiting for a dom search reaction to put the resulted element in an array

Tags: javascript, dom-events, wait, keyup, dispatchevent

I would be gratteful if someone could give me some clue.
I'm trying to dispatch Key up event in a input element after fill in it. Everything is in the Dom. The line code is in a loop. So it gives me something like this :

```js
function makeSomeAction()
{
  var arrayOfElementsNameToClick = []; 

  for( const Name of arrayOfNames){
  myElementInput.value = Name;
  myElementInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('keyup'));
  var myResultOfSearch = document.querySelector("#blabla");
  arrayOfElementsNameToClick.push(myResultOfSearch); 

  }
  
  return arrayOfElementsNameToClick; 

}
```

When i try this piece of code, it's working only for the last Name of arrayOfNames. I also tried to trigger the dispatch Event Element with an addEventListener. but it workking on the same way (last name of the array). It's like i should wait that the dom gives me some result to go to the next iteration of the for loop. The problem is that the dispatch event is not fired, and i can't access to the element of the search. Only the last element of my arrayOfNames.

**What i expect is** that the for loop

- load the right name on the input element,
- wait that the event has been dispatch on this element,
- and then takes the element from the dom with the usual querySelector and put it into an array
- after this only, it go throught the next iteration.

Here's a picture to illustrate my explanation:

[image]
[image]

I've already tried to addEventListener inside the loop without succeed.
If someone could help me, i would be verry gratefull.

Comment: What is the event handler that reacts to the keyup event and write the result to the DOM? Please show us that code as well.

Comment: Notice that `document.querySelector("#blabla")` returns one and the same element every time you call it. You might need to clone that node or get its `.textContent` to get a different result every time. Your array currently contains the same element multiple times, but that element will have only one content - the one that was last written into it.

Comment: I don't know, where can i check this ? I did'nt create any event handler.

Comment: Try stepping through the `dispatchEvent()` call in your code with a debugger. You can also inspect the event handlers bound to an element in the DOM, and place breakpoints on events.

Comment: the document.querySelector - should select the ResultOfSearch Element. I suppose that because the resultOfSearch should change after every name loading, the resultOfSearch should also change. Or maybe it's wrong to think like this, but on the dom, when you tip an different name, the searching element change.

Comment: I already used debugger to step into the dispatchEvent. This one is executed only at the end of my for loop, the number of times my for loop has been runned. So my input.value is varying at each turn, without firing the event. At the end of the different iterations, the dispatch events are fired one after the others.